# Export and import only posts with images in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Please help me to export and import only post data with all featured images. I am using WordPress version 4.3.1. Already try with post export option which WordPress provide but can't export featured images.

Comment: @Milap - the community has discussed the editing of titles, and has decided that flowing phrases in natural English are preferred. Adding home-made tag devices is generally discouraged, [read more here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253076/472495). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have imported your post already then you can use [WP Attachment Export](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-attachment-export/) plugin to export images and then you can import from `Tools->Import` option again.

It will add all your media images and set in your post accordingly automatically.

Answer (score 1):

WordPress doesn't support export Featured Images by default. You can use below plugin for the same.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/export-featured-images/

Read this answer for more details.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66113/import-posts-with-featured-images

Comment: Thanks Milap for quick reply but provided plugin is not tested before 3.9.18 wordpress version.

Comment: Yes but its working fine with latest WP version, i have tested it.